# Eclipse running old programs, no main method

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I created a new package and a new class, and tried to run this program and it keeps either running my old program, or saying it doesn't have a main. I have " build automatically " on.

```
public class test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        increase(x);
        int[] y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        increase(y[0]);
        System.out.println(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
    }

    public static void increase(int[] x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            x[i]++;
    }

    public static void increase(int y) {
        y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: **How** are you trying to run it? Also, Java is pass by value.

Comment: "Old" gives the feel of backwards-compatibility... Rather say "previous".

Comment: what **exactly** is the error?

Comment: is your class name matching the name of the .java file? (Should be caps ideally)

Comment: The code you posted is fine...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Launch Configuration is pointed to "test", and if it isn't, make sure you do  `Run As > Java Application`.

Otherwise you could try a `Project > Clean`.
Clean your workspace and rebuild your Project.

Other than that,the code seems fine.

Comment: @concrete_rose i dont know why you got a -2
Well is it working now?

Comment: @concrete_rose exactly,i dont see the point on getting a -2 for a correct answer.Telling us what IDE he's using would be of great help though.

Comment: @concrete_rose oh i see.We then,our answers are correct.So yeah i upvoted yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on the code:

> Run as -> Java Application

This should work.

Comment: ...and class names should begin with upper case

Comment: @Achilles I got -2 for the same answer :D

Comment: @Achilles I do not know, I did not post the question, I was just trying to help. The solution is pretty obvious. But I would like to know why did I get -2 reputation :D

Comment: Maybe because my answer was short. Maybe I should add some "lorem ipsum" content.

Comment: @Achilles he/she did, it is in the title :)

Comment: @Achilles thank you! And +1 from me :) Hopefully, @Jordan\ Fooks will appreciate the answers :D

Comment: Thanks :D @concrete_rose

Comment: @Achilles weeeeee you got reputation over 50, congrats :D

Comment: yeahh! :D Happy programming! Hopefully you'll have a great reputation ahead! :D